# Delete data from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
private void deleteItem(int position) {
    String itemId = aniPostArrayList.get(position).aniId;

    // Reference to the document in Firestore
    DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("anilar").document(itemId);

    // Delete the document from Firestore
    documentReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            // Document successfully deleted, now update the local list
            aniPostArrayList.remove(position);

            // Notify the adapter that the data set has changed
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Anı başarıyla silindi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // An error occurred while deleting the document
            Toast.makeText(context, "Silme işlemi başarısız: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

"recyclerView" is not updated when I delete data from firebase

When the user presses the delete button, I delete the data from Firebase and this code works. but the list is not updated instantly after the deletion. although it is deleted, it still appears in the list. when I go back and log in again, it is removed from the list.

Comment: Without seeing the code for your list, there's not much we can do to suggest what you might be doing wrong there.  The problem is not necessarily with the code you've shown here.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, here are some resources ([1](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) & [2](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166)) that might help you delete items from Firestore from a RecylerView.